# Javascript ООП?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп

Пытаюсь изучить ООП javascript на реальный примерах и столкнулся с проблемой. Есть такой код:

```
function Widget(containerSelector) {
    this.$container = $(containerSelector);
    this.$widgetIco = this.$container.find('.js-box-ico');
    this.cellRedClass = this.$cell.data('cellRedClass');
    this.bindEvents();
}

Widget.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
    this.$widgetIco
        .on('mouseenter', this.addCell.bind(this))
        .on('mouseleave', this.removeCell.bind(this));
};

Widget.prototype.addCell = function() {
    // Добавить класс к наведенному элементу.
    выбранный элемент при ховере.addClass(this.cellRedClass);
};

$(function() {
    new Widget('.box');
});
```

Не могу понять, как, к примеру, добавить класс в Widget.prototype.addCell к текущему наведенному мышкой элемменту .js-box-ico?

Comment: ну так этот элемент у тебя хранится в `this.$widgetIco`

Comment: у тебя, кстати, нигде не описывается _this.$cell_, поэтому на строке `this.$cell.data('cellRedClass');` все упадет

Comment: на мой взгляд это мало относиться к изучению ООП.

Comment: this.$cell.data('cellRedClass'); все упадет - описывается, просто лишнее тут убрал, чтобы проще было

Comment: всем спасибо (нет), решил сам. Кому интересно:
Widget.prototype.addCell = function(e) {
        $(e.target).addClass(this.cellRedClass);
    };

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget.prototype.addCell = function(e) { 
$(e.target).addClass(this.cellRedClass); 
};
```

Используем e.target